# How change color when click on row dc.datable without losing the filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, dc.js

I have the following problem,
I want to mark the background with another color when I click through the rows of a table in dc.js without losing the filtering that is done.

I have noticed that the command

```
dc.redrawAll();
```

Does not allow the bottom of the row to be filled, but if I remove it, I lose the ability to filter the other graphics when clicking.

```
tabla.on('pretransition', function (table) {
                 table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
                                .on('click',function(d){
                if(filterKeys.indexOf(d.key)===-1)
                  filterKeys.push(d.key);
                else
                  filterKeys = filterKeys.filter(k => k != d.key);
                if(filterKeys.length === 0)
                  foodim.filter(null);
                else 
                    foodim.filterFunction(function(d) {
                    return filterKeys.indexOf(d) !== -1;
                  })
                 //dc.redrawAll();
                });


     table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
                .on('click',function(d){

                     console.log($(this))
                    if($(this).hasClass('bg-info')){
                        $(this).removeClass('bg-info'); 
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('bg-info').siblings().removeClass('bg-info');
                }
                 })

});
```

Can someone help me please.
https://jsfiddle.net/ajey2987/kfmfkLj0/18/

Comment: I don't see any difference in the table with that line enabled or disabled - it just disables the filtering. What am I missing?

Comment: I need the filter when I click on a row in the table (which changes the color of the backgroud). I want to filter on the other graph.
Dc.redrawall does not leave me both options when I click on the row of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this first on mobile and I think hover was covering up the effect you wanted, so I didn't see it either way.

It's usually better to let the styles be driven by the data where possible, rather than having lots of different event handlers working independently to change the styles.

In this case, it appears that the redraw causes the table to replace the elements, losing your class annotation.

Instead we can teach the table how to apply your class based on whether the row's key is in `filterKeys`, also in the `pretransition` handler:

```
                 table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
                   .classed('bg-info', function(d) {
                       return filterKeys.indexOf(d.key)!==-1;
                   });
```

Now we get the desired effect. I think this code easier to reason about, too.

[image: show filters on table]

In addition, I found that the hover effect from bootstrap was making the effect go away when a selected row is hovered. This is because it has a more specific selector. So I added an even more specific one:

```
.table-hover>tbody>tr.bg-info:hover>td {
  background-color: #6EaEe6;
}
```

Fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/e0td50ug/8/